# The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, portable-class-library

I have this portable class library, its settings it Windows Phone 8, Windows Store and .NET 4.5.

I'm trying to add the HttpClient, but after I add it by NuGet its runtime version is v4.0.30319, and when i try to `using System.Net.Http` it states:

```
The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

The following is added as a reference, and was added by NuGet upon install:

- System.Net.Http
- System.Net.Http.Extensions
- System.Net.Http.Primitives

The class I'm trying to use is `HttpClient` in my portable class library :-/

[image]

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of your project dependencies?

Comment: @ken2k ive added the screenshot, Windows Phone 8 supports awaited, but I want to do it by the Portable Class Library way since im thinking of doing other platforms too

Comment: What are the build warnings you are getting?  They are probably related to the APIs not being available.

Answer (score 6):

This MSDN blog [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx) makes it clear that you need to use this special release of HttpClient.

> To use the HttpClient package, right click on your solution, go to the
>   Manage Nuget Packages dialog, search for Id Microsoft.Net.Http, and
>   make sure “Include Prerelease” is turned on.

This was released last February, but I haven't seen any updates to indicate that it is now obsolete.

**EDIT**
Here's the page for the latest version of this [package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http)

Comment: I can't use it with .NET 4.5?

Comment: From the second link "This package is ... only required for projects targeting .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET for Windows Store apps when consuming a library that uses this package."

Comment: So in other words, you should be fine using it with .NET 4.5. I just realized that might not have been clear.